# Translating C++ to ARM Assembly using (MLA instruction)

Tags: c++, arm

I am trying to translate this C++ code:

```
y = y+ x*32;
z = y+ x*x;
```

To ARM assembly assume (x is R1 register, y is R2, z in R3), and I should use **only one assembly instruction for each case**
So, I suggest to do it using (MLA) but I don't know how, can you please help me!!

Comment: Do you have an ARM assembly manual?

Comment: @Galik Yes, I know that the best way to do it is using (MLA) instruction as it make addition and multiplication at the same time. But destnation and the source should be different.

Comment: Okay, so when you tried to solve the problem, what code did you write? What was the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, put your code snippet in an function and create a complete code.

```
void x(void){
    volatile int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
    y = y+ x*32;
    z = y+ x*x;
}
```

Then, compile that on [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/98cnfG).

Result is:

```
x:
        mov     r1, #1
        mov     r2, #2
        mov     r3, #3
        sub     sp, sp, #16
        str     r1, [sp, #4]
        str     r2, [sp, #8]
        str     r3, [sp, #12]
        ldr     r2, [sp, #4]
        ldr     r3, [sp, #8]
        add     r3, r3, r2, lsl #5
        str     r3, [sp, #8]
        ldr     r0, [sp, #4]
        ldr     r1, [sp, #4]
        ldr     r2, [sp, #8]
        mla     r3, r1, r0, r2
        str     r3, [sp, #12]
        add     sp, sp, #16
        bx      lr
```

After that, get the assignment of variables from the values. It looks like `[sp, #4]` is `x`, `[sp, #8]` is `y`, and `[sp, #12]` is `z`.

Finally, using this relation, construct the result.

The answer is:

```
add r2, r2, r1, lsl #5
mla r3, r1, r1, r2
```